# Any alternatives to v2rayN that tunnel the entire traffic on windows?

Tags: proxy, tunnel

I'm not a specialist, just an end user with almost no knowledge about networking.

Whenever I use v2rayN on my laptop and connect to a server, only the traffic of my web browsers is tunneled through the proxy server. Is there any alternative client which can tunnel the entire traffic of my laptop (not just web browsers)?

Comment: Do you need a client compatible with v2rayN servers specifically, or are you looking for any kind of tunnel software in general?

Comment: @user1686 I usually work with a list of proxy servers containing Vmess, Vless, Trojan, and Shadowsocks servers. For Shadowsocks servers, I know that "SSTap-beta" does what I want. Therefore I'm looking for a client compatible with Vmess, Vless, or Trojan servers.

Comment: V2RayN now supports Tun mode which will tunnel all traffic. Check the latest version. The option is on the bottom bar of the main screen of the program. And you have to run as administrator.

Answer (score 4):

You can use nekoray ,a client to use ss , vmess ,vless , ... servers which unlike v2ray has "VPN mode" which will tunnel your entire traffic.

https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1158317)

Comment: It seems that Nekoray is capable of doing what I want, but unfortunately, it gives the following error when I start a server:

"app/proxyman/inbound: failed to listen TCP on 2080
transport/internet: failed to listen on address: 127.0.0.1:2080
transport/internet/tcp: failed to listen TCP on 127.0.0.1:2080
listen tcp 127.0.0.1:2080: bind:
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."

I turned the windows firewall off, but I get the error again.

Comment: @MostafaSaber I guess you should change port in NekoRay's Basic settings